# fontSize change javascript last less than 1s

Tags: javascript, font-size

I'm trying this:

```
</script>

<form action="ej3a.html" onsubmit="Pantalla(this.elements[0].value)">
  Select word size <input type="text" name="Tletra" id="letra"><br>

<script>
```

Then, I send the information summited to a js method

```
function Pantalla(x){

if(x=="Grande")
{

    document.getElementById("todo").style.fontSize="120%";
}
if(x=="Normal")
{
    document.getElementById("todo").style.fontSize="medium";
}
if(x=="Pequeño")
{           
    document.getElementById("todo").style.fontSize="80%";
}

}
```

but, when I summit "Grande" it just increases for a second and later returns to normal size

Note: Forget onmouseover, the change i try to make is on a fielset, which has all text of the web page

```
 <fieldset onmouseover="estiloof()" id="todo">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return = false;
```

at the end of the function to prevent form submission and page reload.